# How to store lot of read-only data in DLL?

Tags: algorithm, memory, dll, fortran

I need a way to store lot of numerical read-only data (double values) in a DLL.
Data must be embedded in source, because it will be changed from time to time - no external tools like Visual Studio etc., only code generation+shell compiler.

I know that it is a bad practice, but this is "business requirement".

I need to store about **2 000 000 of  32-bit float values**. 
This should be about 8MB raw data. Assume that DLL size limit is 100MB.
Language is **Fortran**.

My first thought was to generate value assignments to dynamic array:

```
work(1,1,1,1) = 826
work(1,1,1,2) = 935
work(1,1,1,3) = 712.5
work(1,1,1,4) = 617.1
work(1,1,1,5) = 102.2
```

But final source file has about 70 megabytes, and 0 chances to compile (compiler out of memory error). Besides, even if it would compile, final DLL have size of ~5MB for each 0.5MB of useful data.

Any ideas to format source in more compact way (compiler optimisation friendly?) or maybe pack data to other structure like string/raw binary data and extract on runtime ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of use the `DATA` statement has:

```
  real work(10, 10, 10, 10)
  data work/826, 935, 712.5, 617.1, 102.2/
```

Depending on which compiler you are using, you can even make the data readonly so that any attempt by the program to change any bit of it results in a segfault exception.

Some compilers support the explicit array member enumeration in the data statement:

```
  data work(1,1,1,1)/826/, work(1,1,1,2)/935/, work(1,1,1,3)/712.5/
  data work(1,1,1,4)/617.1/, work(1,1,1,5)/102.2/
```

which will be easier to generate in an unordered way.

Comment: I have a `DATA attribute conflicts with ALLOCATABLE attribute in 'work'`. Dosen't `data` work with dynamic array? I think that this array is too big to create as static

Comment: @killer_PL:  I doubt this would work with a dynamic array.  Anyway, if you want the data to be static and readonly, don't use dynamic.  Use a 1960s-style static array.  I used this to allocate gigantic arrays for its time:  256K, even with a crappy compiler.

Comment: Is error `Fatal Error: Error count reached limit of 25.` a problem with data statement or line length? Can i force compiler to parse longer lines than default limit ?

Comment: @killer_PL:  If I understand the message, it means there are 25 errors.  Ignore that and concentrate on the first error only.

Comment: This was line-length problem, but I reorganised my array to last index size of 10, so I can load array with `data work(1,1,1,:)/xxx,xxx,xxx......./`. For now, biggest succes was compilation to 7.9MB DLL. I will try to find compiler's limit (4x more data didn't compiled - out of memory again).

Comment: My biggest succes is compilation 3 000 000 floats with this solution. Output DLL size is 10.5MB. Compilation needs 2GB RAM with gfortran. More data causes memory error. This solves my problem, but with thin line to fail. I will try string-encoding solution to compare results.

Comment: Solution accepted, to avoid large use of RAM memory we can split source to several files and link it with linker, this can beat a barrier with 3 000 000 floats. Second solution below with Base64 is hard to realise, because it's hard to find proper encoder for this solution.

Comment: Yes, have some pity on the fellow who is going to maintain your program.  The base-64 thing would not make you popular.  If you can keep the numbers most likely to change together in the same include file(s) you'll simplify the update process - change the numbers, only recompile the files which changed, and re-link.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a better solution using Fortran but if everything else fails, you could do the following.

Just treat your 2,000,000 32 bit floats as 8,000,000 bytes and Base64 encode them into a string. You will end up with a 12,800,000 character long string and you could or probably even should split it into several parts. At runtime just reverse everything.

Comment: Nice idea. I think about some larger "space value" than base64, maybe I can put almost raw binary data into a string?

Comment: Base85 yields 6.4 bits per character, 20% overhead. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85 I know nothing about Fortran and how it stores strings or represents non-printable characters in source, but you should be able to use 255 out of 256 characters if strings are zero delimited and even all 256 characters if strings are length prefixed. All assuming 8 bit characters and you are able to escape non-printable characters with not to much overhead.